# Add Response Header to JAX-RS Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, httpresponse, jax-rs

I am trying add some response headers to some of my webservice calls.  I wrote my webservice  using CXF 2.1.2 and JAX-RS.  I need to return an object and I also want to add some headers to the Response.  **Without returning a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object**, how do I add a header to the response and still return my javabean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can inject a reference to the actual HttpServletResponse via the @Context annotation in your webservice and use addHeader() etc. to add your header.

Comment: @Heri - I tried this, HttpServletResponse comes back null.  For Some background I am using Spring for my configuration.  I also tried using @Resource for the response to no avail.  Injecting the HttpServletRequest to the Context does work though...

Comment: This looks like a CXF issue, since it is a specified feature of JAX-RS and I tried it successfully in Jersey. It should be fixed in CXF long ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-1498

Comment: @Heri - Unfortunately I was unable to upgrade the version of CXF in that particular environment, but my issue did appear to be tied to that.  Either way you are correct.