# Custom annotations to set HTTP response headers in a JAX-RS service

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS web service for which I would like to disable the same-origin policy via the new [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) HTTP headers. (I am fully aware of the security implications.)

I'd like to have a custom annotation that lets me set HTTP response headers. For example,

```
@ResponseHeaders({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET"})
// Or, alternatively:
@AllowOrigins({"*"})
public String resourceMethod() { ... }
```

This approach minimizes boilerplate code, but I'm not sure if there's a subtle technical limitation; JAX-RS provides many annotations to handle the HTTP request but not the response, with `@Produces` seeming to be the sole exception.

I also prefer to stay away from too much web.xml configuration, if possible. Without explicitly needing to use a [ResponseBuilder](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) (it's OK if an annotation uses one), is there a clean way to set custom HTTP response headers?

To clarify, I'm looking for *annotations* that integrate with the various ways of setting HTTP response headers in order to minimize boilerplate code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Response Header to JAX-RS Webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493415/add-response-header-to-jax-rs-webservice)

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more streamlined; annotations that use the HttpServletResponse might work. I'm not sure of the subtleties between javax.ws.rs.Response and HttpServletResponse, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the only spec driven approach is to use a custom MessageBodyWriter.  In the writeTo() method, you are passed in a MultivaluedMap which you can set response headers on.  You are also passed the annotations on the resource method invoked (so you can get whatever custom annotation you want).  So read the annotations, set the headers via MultivaluedMap, and then use the OutputStream passed in to write the message body.

In [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink) and possibly other JAX-RS frameworks, you can create custom server side handlers that can also read the annotations on the resource method and do whatever you want (like setting response headers by default).