# JAX-RS — How to return JSON and HTTP status code together?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, http-status-codes

I'm writing a REST web app (NetBeans 6.9, JAX-RS, TopLink Essentials) and trying to return JSON **and** HTTP status code. I have code ready and working that returns JSON when the HTTP GET method is called from the client. Essentially:

```
@Path("get/id")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public M_機械 getMachineToUpdate(@PathParam("id") String id) {

    // some code to return JSON ...

    return myJson;
}
```

But I *also* want to return an HTTP status code (500, 200, 204, etc.) along with the JSON data.

I tried to use `HttpServletResponse`:

```
response.sendError("error message", 500);
```

But this made the browser think it's a "real" 500 so the output web page was a regular HTTP 500 error page.

I want to return an HTTP status code so that my client-side JavaScript can handle some logic depending on it (to e.g. display the error code and message on an HTML page). Is this possible or should HTTP status codes not be used for such thing?

Comment: What's the difference between 500 you want (unreal? :) )  and real 500 ?

Comment: @razor Here real 500 means an HTML error page instead of JSON response

Comment: web browser was not designed to work with JSON, but with HTML pages, so if you respond with 500 (and even some message body), browser can show you just an error message (really depends on browser implementation), just because that's useful for a normal user.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
@GET
@Path("retrieve/{uuid}")
public Response retrieveSomething(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
    if(uuid == null || uuid.trim().length() == 0) {
        return Response.serverError().entity("UUID cannot be blank").build();
    }
    Entity entity = service.getById(uuid);
    if(entity == null) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Entity not found for UUID: " + uuid).build();
    }
    String json = //convert entity to json
    return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Take a look at the [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) class.

Note that you should always specify a content type, especially if you are passing multiple content types, but if every message will be represented as JSON, you can just annotate the method with `@Produces("application/json")`

Comment: It works, but what I don't like about the Response return value is that in my opinion it pollutes your code, specially regarding to any client trying to use it. If you provide an interface returning a Response to a third party, he does not know what type are you really returning. Spring makes it more clear with an annotation, very useful if you always return a status code (i.e. HTTP 204)

Comment: Making that class generic (Response<T>) would be an interesting improvement to jax-rs, to have the advantages of both alternatives.

Comment: There is no need to convert the entity to json somehow. You can do `return Response.status(Response.Status.Forbidden).entity(myPOJO).build();` Works as if you'd `return myPOJO;`, but with additional setting of the HTTP-Status code.

Comment: I think separating the business logic out into a separate service class works well. The endpoint uses Response as return type and it's methods are mostly just calls to the service methods plus the path and param annotations. It cleanly separates the logic from the url / content type mapping (where the rubber hits the road so to speak).

Comment: actually, one can just return the object not wrapping to the Response.

Comment: @Guido Is your comment still valid ?  If so, can you elaborate ?  I can’t see a difference in the return header and body between returning the object and returning a Response.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou I don't know. It is probably outdated since it's 8 years old, but I can't confirm it since I haven't used jax-rs in the last few years.

Comment: If you use Enunciate, you can use `@TypeHint(Class.class)` to provide the specific type to the API docs

Answer (score 211):

There are several use cases for setting HTTP status codes in a REST web service, and at least one was not sufficiently documented in the existing answers (i.e. when you are using auto-magical JSON/XML serialization using JAXB, and you want to return an object to be serialized, but also a status code different than the default 200).

So let me try and enumerate the different use cases and the solutions for each one:

## 1. Error code (500, 404,...)

The most common use case when you want to return a status code different than `200 OK` is when an error occurs.

For example:

- an entity is requested but it doesn't exist (404)
- the request is semantically incorrect (400)
- the user is not authorized (401)
- there is a problem with the database connection (500)
- etc..

### a) Throw an exception

In that case, I think that the cleanest way to handle the problem is to throw an exception. This exception will be handled by an `ExceptionMapper`, that will translate the exception into a response with the appropriate error code.

You can use the default `ExceptionMapper` that comes pre-configured with Jersey (and I guess it's the same with other implementations) and throw any of the existing sub-classes of `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`. These are pre-defined exception types that are pre-mapped to different error codes, for example:

- BadRequestException (400)
- InternalServerErrorException (500)
- NotFoundException (404)

Etc. You can find the list here: [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html)

Alternatively, you can define your own custom exceptions and `ExceptionMapper` classes, and add these mappers to Jersey by the mean of the `@Provider` annotation ([source of this example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/03/exception-handling-in-jax-rs-resteasy-with-exceptionmapper/)):

```
public class MyApplicationException extends Exception implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MyApplicationException() {
        super();
    }
    public MyApplicationException(String msg)   {
        super(msg);
    }
    public MyApplicationException(String msg, Exception e)  {
        super(msg, e);
    }
}
```

Provider :

```
    @Provider
    public class MyApplicationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<MyApplicationException> 
    {
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(MyApplicationException exception) 
        {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();  
        }
    }
```

Note: you can also write ExceptionMappers for existing exception types that you use.

### b) Use the Response builder

Another way to set a status code is to use a `Response` builder to build a response with the intended code.

In that case, your method's return type must be `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`. This is described in various other responses such as hisdrewness' accepted answer and looks like this :

```
@GET
@Path("myresource({id}")
public Response retrieveSomething(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ...
    Entity entity = service.getById(uuid);
    if(entity == null) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Resource not found for ID: " + uuid).build();
    }
    ...
}
```

## 2. Success, but not 200

Another case when you want to set the return status is when the operation was successful, but you want to return a success code different than 200, along with the content that you return in the body.

A frequent use case is when you create a new entity (`POST` request) and want to return info about this new entity or maybe the entity itself, together with a `201 Created` status code.

One approach is to use the response object just like described above and set the body of the request yourself. However, by doing this you loose the ability to use the automatic serialization to XML or JSON provided by JAXB.

This is the original method returning an entity object that will be serialized to JSON by JAXB:

```
@Path("/")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public User addUser(User user){
    User newuser = ... do something like DB insert ...
    return newuser;
}
```

This will return a JSON representation of the newly created user, but the return status will be 200, not 201.

Now the problem is if I want to use the `Response` builder to set the return code, I have to return a `Response` object in my method. How do I still return the `User` object to be serialized?

### a) Set the code on the servlet response

One approach to solve this is to obtain a servlet request object and set the response code manually ourselves, like demonstrated in Garett Wilson's answer :

```
@Path("/")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public User addUser(User user, @Context final HttpServletResponse response){

    User newUser = ...

    //set HTTP code to "201 Created"
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
    try {
        response.flushBuffer();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    return newUser;
}
```

The method still returns an entity object and the status code will be 201.

Note that to make it work, I had to flush the response. This is an unpleasant resurgence of low-level Servlet API code in our nice JAX_RS resource, and much worse, it causes the headers to be unmodifiable after this because they were already sent on the wire.

### b) Use the response object with the entity

The best solution, in that case, is to use the Response object and set the entity to be serialized on this response object. It would be nice to make the Response object generic to indicate the type of the payload entity in that case, but is not the currently the case.

```
@Path("/")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response addUser(User user){

    User newUser = ...

    return Response.created(hateoas.buildLinkUri(newUser, "entity")).entity(restResponse).build();
}
```

In that case, we use the created method of the Response builder class in order to set the status code to 201. We pass the entity object (user) to the response via the entity() method.

The result is that the HTTP code is 401 as we wanted, and the body of the response is the exact same JSON as we had before when we just returned the User object. It also adds a location header.

The Response class has a number of builder method for different statuses (stati ?) such as :

Response.accepted()
Response.ok()
Response.noContent()
Response.notAcceptable()

NB: the hateoas object is a helper class that I developed to help generate resources URIs. You will need to come up with your own mechanism here ;)

That's about it.

I hope this lengthy response helps somebody :)

Comment: I wonder if there's a clean way to return the data object itself instead of the response. The `flush` is indeed dirty.

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine: 401 doesn't mean _the user_ isn't authorized. It means _the client_ isn't authorized, because the server does not know who you are. If a logged/otherwise recognized user is not permitted to do a certain action, the correct response code is 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 72):

The answer by hisdrewness will work, but it modifies the whole approach to letting a provider such as Jackson+JAXB automatically convert your returned object to some output format such as JSON. Inspired by an Apache CXF [post](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/JAX-RS-send-a-specific-object-in-response-amp-set-status-code-td5086867.html) (which uses a CXF-specific class) I've found one way to set the response code that should work in any JAX-RS implementation: inject an HttpServletResponse context and manually set the response code. For example, here is how to set the response code to `CREATED` when appropriate.

```
@Path("/foos/{fooId}")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Foo setFoo(@PathParam("fooID") final String fooID, final Foo foo, @Context final HttpServletResponse response)
{
  //TODO store foo in persistent storage
  if(itemDidNotExistBefore) //return 201 only if new object; TODO app-specific logic
  {
    response.setStatus(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
  }
  return foo;  //TODO get latest foo from storage if needed
}
```

*Improvement:* After finding another related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625289/421049), I learned that one can inject the `HttpServletResponse` as a member variable, even for singleton service class (at least in RESTEasy)!! This is a much better approach than polluting the API with implementation details. It would look like this:

```
@Context  //injected response proxy supporting multiple threads
private HttpServletResponse response;

@Path("/foos/{fooId}")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Foo setFoo(@PathParam("fooID") final String fooID, final Foo foo)
{
  //TODO store foo in persistent storage
  if(itemDidNotExistBefore) //return 201 only if new object; TODO app-specific logic
  {
    response.setStatus(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
  }
  return foo;  //TODO get latest foo from storage if needed
}
```

Comment: You can actually combine the approaches: annotate the method with `@Produces`, and don't specify the media type in the final `Response.ok`, and you'll get your return object correctly JAXB-serialized into the appropriate media type to match the request. (I just tried this with a single method that could return either XML or JSON: the method itself doesn't need to mention either, except in the `@Produces` annotation.)

Comment: You are right Garret. My example was more of an illustration of the emphasis of providing a content type. Our approaches are similar, but the idea of using a `MessageBodyWriter` and `Provider` allows for implicit content negotiation, although it seems your example is missing some code. Here's another answer I provided that illustrates this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support/5163207#5163207

Comment: I'm unable to override the status code in `response.setStatus()`. The only way to send for example a **404 Not Found** response is to set the response status code `response.setStatus(404)` en then close the output stream `response.getOutputStream().close()` so JAX-RS cannot reset my status.

Comment: I was able to use this approach to set a 201 code, but had to add a try-catch block with `response.flushBuffer()` in order to avoid the framework overriding my response code. Not very clean.

Comment: @RobJuurlink, if you want specifically to return a `404 Not Found`, it may be easier just to use `throw new NotFoundException()`.

Answer (score 42):

If you like to keep your resource layer clean of `Response` objects, then I recommend you use `@NameBinding` and binding to implementations of `ContainerResponseFilter`.

Here's the meat of the annotation:

```
package my.webservice.annotations.status;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Status {
  int CREATED = 201;
  int value();
}
```

Here's the meat of the filter:

```
package my.webservice.interceptors.status;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class StatusFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    if (containerResponseContext.getStatus() == 200) {
      for (Annotation annotation : containerResponseContext.getEntityAnnotations()) {
        if(annotation instanceof Status){
          containerResponseContext.setStatus(((Status) annotation).value());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then the implementation on your resource simply becomes:

```
package my.webservice.resources;

import my.webservice.annotations.status.StatusCreated;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/my-resource-path")
public class MyResource{
  @POST
  @Status(Status.CREATED)
  public boolean create(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Keeps the API clean, nice answer. Would it be possible to parametrize your annotation like @Status(code = 205), and have the interceptor replace the code with whatever you specify? I think that would basically give you an annotation for overriding the codes whenever you need to.

Comment: @user2800708, I already did this for my local code, updated the answer as you suggested.

Comment: Nice, thanks. With this and a few othe tricks I'm basically now able to clean up the REST APIs in my code, so that it conforms to a simple Java interface with no mention of REST in it; its just another RMI mechanism.

Comment: Instead of looping for annotations in StatusFilter, you can annotate the filter with @ Status in addition to @ Provider. Then the filter will only be called on resources that are annotated with @ Status. This is the purpose of @ NameBinding

Comment: Good callout @trevorism. There's one not-so-nice side effect of annotating `StatusFilter` with `@Status`: you either need to supply a default for the annotation's `value` field, or declare one when annotating the class (ex: `@Status(200)`). This is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

I found it very useful to build also a json message with repeated code, like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response authUser(JsonObject authData) {
    String email = authData.getString("email");
    String password = authData.getString("password");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    if (email.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getEmail()) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getPassword())) {
        json.put("status", "success");
        json.put("code", Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
        json.put("message", "User " + authData.getString("email") + " authenticated.");
        return Response.ok(json.toString()).build();
    } else {
        json.put("status", "error");
        json.put("code", Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode());
        json.put("message", "User " + authData.getString("email") + " not found.");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(json.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to change the status code because of an exception, with JAX-RS 2.0 you can implement an ExceptionMapper like this. This handles this kind of exception for the whole app.

```
@Provider
public class UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<EJBAccessException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EJBAccessException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode()).build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your WS-RS needs raise an error why not just use the WebApplicationException?

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("{id}")
public MyEntity getFoo(@PathParam("id") long id,  @QueryParam("lang")long idLanguage) {

if (idLanguage== 0){
    // No URL parameter idLanguage was sent
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    builder.entity("Missing idLanguage parameter on request");
    Response response = builder.build();
    throw new WebApplicationException(response);
    }
... //other stuff to return my entity
return myEntity;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion WebApplicationExceptions are not suitable for client side errors because they throw big stack traces. Client errors should not throw server side stack traces and pollute the logging with it.

Answer (score 5):

JAX-RS has support for standard/custom HTTP codes.  See ResponseBuilder and ResponseStatus, for example:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#status%28javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status%29

Keep in mind that JSON information is more about the data associated with the resource/application.  The HTTP codes are more about the status of the CRUD operation being requested.  (at least that is how it's supposed to be in REST-ful systems)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Please look at the example here, it best illustrates the problem and how it is solved in the latest (2.3.1) version of Jersey.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e3586

It basically involves defining a custom Exception and keeping the return type as the entity. When there is an error, the exception is thrown, otherwise, you return the POJO.

Comment: I would like to add that the example of interest is the one where they define their own exception class and build a `Response` in it. Just look for the `CustomNotFoundException` class and maybe copy it to your post.

Comment: I use this approach for errors and I like it. But it is no applicable to success codes (different then 200) such as '201 created'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using JAX-RS, but I've got a similar scenario where I use:

```
response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
```

Comment: It does for me using Spring MVC but there is an easy way to find out!

Answer (score 1):

Also, notice that by default Jersey will override the response body in case of an http code 400 or more.

In order to get your specified entity as the response body, try to add the following init-param to your Jersey  in your web.xml configuration file :

```
    <init-param>
        <!-- used to overwrite default 4xx state pages -->
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me. Injecting the messageContext via annotated setter and setting the status code in my "add" method.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;

public class FlightReservationService {

    MessageContext messageContext;

    private final Map<Long, FlightReservation> flightReservations = new HashMap<>();

    @Context
    public void setMessageContext(MessageContext messageContext) {
        this.messageContext = messageContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<FlightReservation> list() {
        return flightReservations.values();
    }

    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @GET
    public FlightReservation get(Long id) {
        return flightReservations.get(id);
    }

    @Path("/")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @POST
    public void add(FlightReservation booking) {
        messageContext.getHttpServletResponse().setStatus(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
        flightReservations.put(booking.getId(), booking);
    }

    @Path("/")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @PUT
    public void update(FlightReservation booking) {
        flightReservations.remove(booking.getId());
        flightReservations.put(booking.getId(), booking);
    }

    @Path("/{id}")
    @DELETE
    public void remove(Long id) {
        flightReservations.remove(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25701949/2787159) of [Nthalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491764/nthalk) with [Microprofile OpenAPI](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api) you can align the return code with your documentation using [@APIResponse](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/openapi/annotations/responses/APIResponse.java) annotation.

This allows tagging a JAX-RS method like

```java
@GET
@APIResponse(responseCode = "204")
public Resource getResource(ResourceRequest request)
```

You can parse this standardized annotation with a [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/8/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html)

```java
@Provider
public class StatusFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() == 200) {
            for (final var annotation : responseContext.getEntityAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation instanceof APIResponse response) {
                    final var rawCode = response.responseCode();
                    final var statusCode = Integer.parseInt(rawCode);

                    responseContext.setStatus(statusCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A caveat occurs when you put multiple annotations on your method like

```java
@APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "first use case")
@APIResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "because you can")
public Resource getResource(ResourceRequest request)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using jersey 2.0 with message body readers and writers.  I had my method return type as a specific entity which was also used in the implementation of the message body writer and i was returning the same pojo, a SkuListDTO.
    @GET
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @Path("/skuResync")

```
public SkuResultListDTO getSkuData()
    ....
return SkuResultListDTO;
```

all i changed was this,  I left the writer implementation alone and it still worked.

```
public Response getSkuData()
...
return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(dfCoreResultListDTO).build();
```