# Jersey Error: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

i'm trying to implement a small REST API using Jersey as framework, in principle the code worked fine but when I try to do a 'GET' of a hash table, I get the following error:

```
nov 23, 2014 4:27:40 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor aroundReadFrom
GRAVE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=java.util.Map<upf.dad.proyecto.New, upf.dad.proyecto.Term>.
1440 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.testJob3 threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=java.util.Map<upf.dad.proyecto.New, upf.dad.proyecto.Term>.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:810)
)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:313)
    at upf.dad.proyecto.HotTopicDetector.News(HotTopicDetector.java:110)
    at upf.dad.proyecto.ScheduledTestJob3.execute(ScheduledTestJob3.java:11)
1440 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - Job (DEFAULT.testJob3 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=java.util.Map<upf.dad.proyecto.New, upf.dad.proyecto.Term>.]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=java.util.Map<upf.dad.proyecto.New, upf.dad.proyecto.Term>.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:810)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:368)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:846)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$600(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:705)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:313)
    at upf.dad.proyecto.HotTopicDetector.News(HotTopicDetector.java:110)
    at upf.dad.proyecto.ScheduledTestJob3.execute(ScheduledTestJob3.java:11)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the problematic line:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget targetGetAllNews = client.target("http://localhost:15000").path("news/getAllNews");


    Map<New, Term> NewsAll = targetGetAllNews.request(
             MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(new GenericType<Map<New, Term>>(){});
```

and this is how I implemented the service:

```
@GET
@Path("/getAllNews")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<New, Term> getAllNews() {
    return NewsCrawler.getNewAndTerm();
}
```

pom.xml (maven dependencies)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>upf.dad.proyecto</groupId>
<artifactId>JAXRS-proyecto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
<!-- Rome RSS and Atom utilities @ http://rometools.github.io/rome/ -->        
<dependency>
        <groupId>rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>             
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->         
<dependency>             
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>             
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>             
        <version>1.8.1</version>               
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Server side configuration:

```
public class NewsCrawlerRestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(15000).build();
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(NewsCrawlerServices.class, HotTopicDetectorServices.class);
    config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
    HttpServer server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);
    System.out.println("Server started...");

    }
}
```

Error registering Jackson in the client:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:866)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:810)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:368)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:846)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$600(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:705)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:417)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:313)
        at upf.dad.proyecto.HotTopicDetector.News(HotTopicDetector.java:112)
        at upf.dad.proyecto.ScheduledTestJob3.execute(ScheduledTestJob3.java:11)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class upf.dad.proyecto.New]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._handleUnknownKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:580)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:170)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:404)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.createContextual(MapDeserializer.java:232)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:572)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:386)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1380)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1228)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:677)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:777)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:264)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
```

New Class:

```
package upf.dad.proyecto;

import java.util.Date;

public class New {

private String tittle;
private String description;
private Date date;
private String link;

public New(){

}

public New(String t, String d, Date date, String l){
    this.tittle = t;
    this.description = d;
    this.date = date;
    this.link = l;
}

public String getTittle() {
    return tittle;
}

public void setTittle(String tittle) {
    this.tittle = tittle;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "New [tittle=" + tittle + ", description=" + description
            + ", date=" + date + ", link=" + link + "]";
}


}
```

Term class:

```
package upf.dad.proyecto;

public class Term {

private String word;

public Term(){

}

public Term(String word){
    this.word = word;

}

public String getWord(){
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String _word){
    word = _word;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Termino =" + word + "]";
}
}
```

can someone help me please to return the map?

Comment: I know this is a client side problem, but can you show the server application configuration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see you have two different provider dependencies `jersey-media-moxy` and `jersey-media-json-jackson`. I've always had a problem with `Maps` with MOXy. I guess they don't play well. Seems you will need to use an adapter to make it play nice, as seen [here from Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360732/2587435).

That being said, I requested (in the comments above) to see your Server side configuration, as MOXy will auto configure itself, and take precedence over the `jersey-media-json-jackson`. Why, I'm not sure, this is just what I've always experienced. So I'm curious how the Server side didn't fail even before the response came back to the client. Unless you confgiure the `JacksonFeature` with the server application, in which you should have also configured it with the client. (This is only the case, because you also have MOXy dependency).

Anyway, if you don't want to go through the hassle creating adapters, as seen in the link above, just get rid of the `jersey-media-moxy` dependency. `jersey-media-json-jackson` will also auto configure it feature. You should just use one or the other.

---

**As an aside:**

`@Path("/getAllNews")`. Path segments should be nouns, unless they are controller resources, which normally perform some action, other than normal CRUD operations (e.g. `/register`). The HTTP method already consists of the verb to which each CRUD action should be performed.

- **C**reate - POST
- **R**etriecve - GET
- **U**pdate = PUT
- **D**elete - DELETE

Just some semantics to consider :-)

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is with the `New` key. Jackson doesn't know how to deserialize this. Since you are willing to switch the key and value type, just change the `toString` to return the `name` in the `Term` class, and it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the post with the required information. As you can see, to return the map I use the Jackson as JSON provider adding the dependency to the pom.xml file and registering it in the ResourceConfig object before starting the HttpServer but still not working...

Comment: Try registering it with the client also, since the problem is on the client side (since the problem is with the client) i.e. `client.register(...)`. Since you have the MOXy still, the client may be implicitly registered with MOXy.

Comment: thanks for the help, again, I updated the post with the error I get when I register the client...I have been considering also use the adapter, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: please show the `New` and `Term` class. I created my own to test and it worked fine.

Comment: You can see the classes requested, thanks.


Could you give an example of how to use `GenericEntity`?

Comment: I see the problem. Keys in JSON are supposed to be Strings. If you want to use an object, 1) You need to create a custom serializer that will serialize and deserializer the object to a String 2) it'll look funky in JSON

Comment: Are you sure you meant for the `New` to be the key, and not the other way around? `Term` only has one field, which will be easier to represent as a key. `New` has four fields, which is an awkward key

Comment: I can change the order without any problem, that would solve the problem?

Comment: No you still need a serializer/deserializer, but it's pretty easy. I just suggested switching the order, because trying to represent 4 fields as a json key just looks weird. I'll put together something. Give me a few minutes

Comment: So it actually looks like just using the `Term` type for the key makes it work. But the actual text in the json is the `toString` So you can just have it return the `name`. No need for any serializers

Comment: So, If I change the `toString` method to return only the name, will work?

I get the same first error: `GRAVE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=java.util.Map` etc. by just changing the `toString` method like this:

`public String toString() {return word;}`

Comment: Did you register the client with the JacksonFeature. You should get rid of the MOXy dependency if you're not going to use it. The Jackson module should autoconfigure itself. But the MOXy will take precedence

Comment: Yes, I closed Eclipse, I have reopened and no longer returns an error. Thank you very much!