# Jersey application fails to return JSON representation for a simple POJO

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, netty

I'm trying to use Jersey RS to return JSON for a POJO. This is **not** a servlet and there is no servlet container. The Jersey is being setup from within [Netty](http://netty.io/)  (not Jetty). I can get Jersey to return APPLICATION_XML but APPLICATION_JSON on same resource throws an exception saying No Message Body writer for my domain class was found. I have included jersey-json and jackson-jaxrs modules in pom.xml.

Here's how the ResourceConfig is being setup :

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, RESOURCES_PACKAGE);
props.put(PROPERTY_BASE_URI, "http://localhost:9000/");
props.put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);    
ContainerFactory.createContainer(JerseyHandler.class, new PackagesResourceConfig(props));
```

where JerseyHandler is my Netty Handler class.
The resource is very simple:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestData get() {
           return new TestData();
    }
```

TestData is the simplest model class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestData {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public TestData() {}
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   } 

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
}
```

Here's the exception when trying to access "/test" :

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.xyz.models.TestData, and Java type class com.xyz.models.TestData, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

I have tried including Context classes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support) but still no luck.

I can't imagine returning JSON from Jersey can be that hard. All examples on internet assume you're using Jersey from a servlet container but I am not! thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jackson-core and jackson-mapper librairies ? That is what we need to get JSON serialization working.

Comment: mvn dependency:tree shows both jackson-core and jackson-mapper-asl modules are pulled in by jersey-json. Any other ideas?