# How to produce JSON output with Jersey 1.17.1 using JAXB

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey, jackson, jersey-1.0

There is a correct answer to this question already on this site. The problem is that the [question is for Jersey 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027097/how-to-produce-json-output-with-jersey-1-6-using-jaxb) and [the correct answer for Jersey 1.17.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662700/61624) is buried at the bottom.  I figured I'd create a correct question for this answer so that it'd be easier to find help for people struggling with this (like I was).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to add this to your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Then, take any of the classes you want to serialize across the wire and add this annotation to the top of them:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class ...
```

Then add the appropriate jars to the classpath.  It's not enough to add the Jersey jars, you also need to add jackson.  I downloaded the zip that includes 12 different jars.  Once I added all 12 jars to my classpath I finally got rid of the error and works great returning JSON.

I hope this helps somebody.

**Download Zip with 12 Jars:** 
Here is a link to the zip file that contains the 12 jar files: [jersey-archive-1.17.zip](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-archive/1.17.1/jersey-archive-1.17.1.zip)

**For Maven Users:**
Add the following to your pom.xml to get the 12 jars individually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It works for me. But I would like to have the maven dependencies for jersey3 !