# Using MessageBodyReader with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, deserialization

I'm using JAX-RS to provide rest API in my Java application and I'm having problem with deserializing objects that contain other objects. For such objects (beans), upon deserializing, I get the error "A message body reader for Java class ClassName, and Java type class ClassNAme2, and MIME media type application/json was not found". I googled the error and figured out that there should be something wrong regarding "MessageBodyReader"; however, I'm not quite sure what is going on and how I should use this interface to address the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do all of your object (including the contained objects) have JAXB annotations?

Comment: None of the objects are annotated.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum try adding JAXB's `@XmlRootElement` annotation to your classes that are involved in serialization. See if that eliminates the error and then add more JAXB annotations as necessary...

Answer (score 0):

@user1558274, Make sure you are not missing jersey-json-1.8.jar or jersey-server jar. And you need to annotate your POJO's with @XmlRootElement. Click following links to get know more.

- [Resourse 1](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)
- [Resourse 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support)