# can someone explain using servlets and setting it up in web.xml

Tags: java, rest, servlets, web.xml

I'm only a beginner but I have gone through one beginners Java training course where  we also covered some aspects of REST so I'm starting to understand things a little bit better. I would really like to understand more about servlets and how web.xml is used to set them up. The below is a web.xml that I was using on my project while I was on this training course.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.arpit.java2blog.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Righ now I can only understand some of it. I can understand some of what `<servlet-name>`, `<servlet-class>`, `<servlet-mapping>` and `<url-pattern>`do.

But I'm really struggling to understand what `<init-param>`, `<param-name>` and `<param-value>` in generally do. I've been trying to google to find some information that would explain these in very simplistic manner but I have not had much joy.

I really want to understand what these two sections below do:

```
`<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.arpit.java2blog.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>`
```

I can understand bit of what the first section relates to because my controller classes are in package `<param-value>org.arpit.java2blog.controller</param-value>`. But what does and why is the param-name as `com.sun.jersey.config.property`? I cannot find any package with this name.

I understand the the second init=param section has something to do with the jersey-json jars and that's about it.

I would be genuinely grateful if someone could explain some of these things in a very simplistic English if possible (English is not our native language in Estonia). I'm working really hard to become a better in programming and I could use bit of help.

Kind regards.

Comment: It's setting up [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

Comment: Are you clear with the generic use of these  in a web.xml or is it this specific case your are facing issue with?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal - Thank you. The answer is bit of both. I'm having trouble of setting up a project with REST, Maven and Tomcat. So I thought I should try to learn more about it but I'm struggling really to understand how POM and web.xml work. I had some help setting up things up with this project before when I was using Eclipse. Now I'm trying to set it up on IntelliJ but now I'm on my own. I created a new post with this specific problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031725/cannot-get-rest-response-with-postman-java-intellij-tomcat-9-maven

Answer (score 0):

Those are the initialization parameters for the servlet class:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.
```

If you take a look source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.0.2/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.java#ServletContainer.configure%28com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebConfig%2Ccom.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig%2Ccom.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplication%29):

> ...If the initialization parameter
>   "**com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass**" or
>   "**javax.ws.rs.Application**" is not present and a initialization
>   parameter "**com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages**" is present (see
>   **com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES**) a
>   new instance of **com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig** is
>   created. The initialization parameter
>   "**com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages**" MUST be set to provide one
>   or more package names. Each package name MUST be separated by ';'. The
>   package names are added as a property value to a Map instance using
>   the property name (@link PackagesResourceConfig#PROPERTY_PACKAGES}.
>   Any additional initialization parameters are then added to the Map
>   instance. Then that Map instance is passed to the constructor of
>   [com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.0.2/com/sun/jersey/api/core/PackagesResourceConfig.java#PackagesResourceConfig).

And the second one for [PojoMappingFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161466/how-do-i-use-the-jersey-json-pojo-support)

Comment: this was helpful.