# How can I send a response code and content from a resource?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jax-RS and jersey to implement a web service, I can use the Response class to send an response code to the client:

```
Response.status(Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).build();
```

Or I can send Response content:

```
Response.ok("Respose").build();
```

Is there a way to send an arbitrary response for an arbitrary code?

Specifically I am trying to send the authorization code in a redirect for OAuth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [JAX-RS — How to return JSON and HTTP status code together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together)

Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Hello World").build();