# 415 error when sending json data back to java rest service using AJAX

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an ajax request on my front end that sends a JSON doc to a rest service implementation.  It is wired up through Spring and the @GET request in the REST service works well.

The issue is that whenever i try to use the @POST method it always throws a 415 error.

I have tried manipulating how i send it back and the type of variable that is accepted in the post method according to various guides online but I am not sure where to look next.

I have double checked that i do have data being sent to the @POST method but I feel like it is not parsing the JSON at all and throwing the error.

Unfortunately i dont see how to fix that if it is the issue.

Below i have dumbed everything down to a simple form that still produces the 415 error.

AJAX Request:

```
function post_request(json_data) {
    $j.ajax({
        url : '../api/createDisplayGroup/postHtmlVar/' + containerID + '/' + containerType,
        data: JSON.stringify(json_data),
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'post'
    }).done(function(response) {
        run_update(response);
    }).error(function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error getting request');
    });
};
```

Spring XML:

```
<jaxrs:server id="displayGroupService" address="/createDisplayGroup">  
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>  
                <ref bean="peopleFilterRestService" />  
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>  
      <jaxrs:providers>  
                <ref bean="jacksonJsonProvider"/>  
                <!-- disable XHR token check - allow external sources to call the service -->
                <!--ref bean="securityInterceptor" /-->  
      </jaxrs:providers>  
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="peopleFilterRestService" class="mil.milsuite.community.rest.PeopleFilterRestService">
    <property name="peopleFilterService" ref="peopleFilterService"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="peopleFilterService" class="mil.milsuite.community.members.service.PeopleFilterServiceImpl">
    <property name="communityManager" ref="communityManager"/> 
    <property name="socialGroupManager" ref="socialGroupManagerImpl"/>
</bean>
```

REST Implementation (only @POST):

```
@POST
 @Path("/postHtmlVar/{containerId}/{contentType}")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<TabDefinition> postHtml(@PathParam("containerId") String containerId, @PathParam("contentType") String contentType, List<TabDefinition> displayGroups) {
     Long contId = Long.parseLong(containerId);
     Long contType = Long.parseLong(contentType);


     //return convertToResponse(peopleFilterService.getDisplayGroups(contId, contType));*/

     return testDisplayGroup();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are receiving is as follows:

> **415 Unsupported Media Type**
>
> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format.
>   ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#415))

The cause may be the `$j.ajax` call, try adding the `contentType` argument, e.g.:

```
...
$j.ajax({
    url : '../api/createDisplayGroup/postHtmlVar/' + containerID + '/' + containerType,
    data: JSON.stringify(json_data),
    dataType: 'json',
    type : 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json'
...
```

This will then match the value of the `@Consumes` annotation used by your `postHtml` method, note that:

> The @Consumes annotation is used to specify which MIME media types of representations a resource can accept, or consume, from the client. ([Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html#6nmq2cp2i))

By default the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call's media type will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so your handler method will not be matched, resulting in the `415` error.

**Aside:** In the ajax call, `contentType` specifies the type of data to be sent to the server whereas `dataType` specifies the type of data that will be returned.

Comment: so instead of   "type: json"  in the ajax call use "contentType: 'application/json'" ?

Comment: You would need to add `contentType` in addition to `dataType`, check  the updated answer.

Comment: that seems to at least be doing something different... getting a 500 error now ... im guessing that im going to need a different type in the method Definition...   

if what im sending in is an array of JSON objects can i just use List<JsonObject> ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know off the top of my head - it might be worth asking a new question about this, however, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4687942/69875) may help.