# How to get a status code?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm a bit new to JAX-RS.

I have the following code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget resource = client.target("/foo/bar/" + id);

final String xml = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
```

This is a stupid question, but how exactly could I get the response and it's status code from here?
The output is a `String`...

Comment: Please take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together

Comment: The thing is -- on the server-side I am returning a object (`Foo`) which is automatically marshalled by `Jersey` + `Jackson`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Invocation.Builder builder = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
Response resp = builder.get ();
int status = resp.getStatus ();
String xml = resp.getEntity (String.class);
```