# How to return http status code for exceptions in rest services

Tags: java, rest, http, cxf

In my application I have different layers like the rest layer, service layer and DB layer, according to business scenarios I am trowing different business exceptions from the service layer.

But now, I have to set different HTTP codes like 400, 403, 409, 412.. to REST responses.

How can I set different HTTP status codes based on different scenarios?

Which is the most feasible way like: aspect, exception mapper, or ....?

Since I can set HTTP status only once in rest layer (
[referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together) ), I am not able to map to different HTTP codes because my exception is from service layer.

My exception class looks like this:

```
public class BusinessException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BusinessException(ErrorEnumeration error) {

    }
    public BusinessException(Exception e, ErrorEnumeration error) {

    }
}
```

and the exception will be thrown from the service like this:

```
 throw new BusinessException(ErrorEnumeration.VALIDATION_FAILED);
```

Please help by suggesting a solution

Answer (score 9):

You can use exceptions defined in jax-rs or you can use your own exceptions. Fist catch your business exceptions and convert them to jax-rs versions. For example, for 404 you can throw `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException.`

You can also write your own exceptions by extending them from `javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException`

Here is an example for 409-Conflict status exception

```
import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ConflictException extends ClientErrorException{

    public ConflictException(Response.Status status) {
        super(Response.Status.CONFLICT); // 409
    }
}
```

### Update

Most simple and feasible way is catching your business exceptions and re-throw them with jax-rs exceptions.

```
try{
  businessService.executeBusinessRule();
}catch (BusinessException e){
  // It is better if your BusinessException has some child class to handle
  if(e.getError() == ErrorEnumeration.VALIDATION_FAILED){
    throw new BadRequestException();
  }else{
    throw new ConflictException();
  }
}
```

If you are using spring you can always catch these exceptions using aop.

```
@Aspect
public class BusinessExceptionInterceptor{
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.your.service.packge..* (..))", throwing = "e")
public void errorInterceptor(BusinessException e) {
   // re-throw again...
}
```

### Update 2

Also it is better to define a new exception instead of reusing same exception with different state. You can define a new ValidationException which extends from BusinessException like this.

```
public class ValidationException extends BusinessException{

    public ValidationException() {
        super(ErrorEnumeration.VALIDATION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

By using this way you can still handle all the BusinessException but it is easier to identify or map them to Jax-rs exceptions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a quick reply :) I have updated the question.

Comment: is it good add one more method in my "BusinessException" class like below ?

public BusinessException(ErrorEnumeration error, Response.Status httpStatus) {
        }

So that i can send the status while throwing itsef.

Comment: No not good. Your business layer should not be aware of which layer using it. You must detailed your exceptions, then handle them properly and last rethrow them in a form with status code.

Comment: oh ok, but if i want to re-throw as u said i have to write catch or new exception class (referring your answer).Problem is i have around 35 different enumerations according business scenarios, i can't catch 35 exceptions for re-mapping or creating new classes also not recommendable.In this case how can i move ahead ?

Comment: Yes that will be a problem :). Just catch them with `businessException` exception. Then write a utility which generates exceptions according to your enumeration. You may use aop to catch them. This way you do not need to write `try...catch` statements. But you need to integrate aop, if you did not already

Comment: ConflictException is not in Jersey 2 anymore. I am digging to see what I can replace it with (after attempts to migrate from Jersey 1.18 to 2.16)