# jetty websocket server: Send customer status code based on application logic

Tags: java, websocket, server, jetty

I am writing a Websocket server using Jetty.

My handler code:

```
public class WebSocketServerHandler {

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("Close: statusCode=" + statusCode + ", reason=" + reason);

    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {

    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onBinaryMethod(Session session, byte data[], int offset, int length) {

    }
}
```

One of my requirement is to send custom status code based on business logic insde `onBinaryMethod`
**e.g: Send 1001 as status code for timeout**(Jetty already support this)

I am not sure where to set these status codes. I have tried following but that doesn't seems to work.

```
Session().getUpgradeResponse().setStatusCode();
```

Comment: Which status code are you asking about? You seem to be confusing HTTP response status codes (3 digits) and WebSocket close status codes (4 digits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***WebSockets***

Here is the [`RFC`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4) regarding the status codes of WebSocket.

During the communication with the `socket` You are not supposed to send such information in status codes. Send a `message` instead with the information which is needed by the client.

**If you happen to be interested in closing codes** you can supply this information on the `Session` object as follows:

```
session.close(new CloseReason(YOUR_NUMBER, "Your reason"));
```

***REST***

If You rely on those codes use ***REST services***, there are a lot of options there:

- Throw a specific exception
- Use response builder and return the response
- Inject the context

I think the easiest way to achieve Your goal is to use [`setStatus(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)):

```
@Context 
HttpServletResponse response;

@Path("/method")
public void onBinaryMethod() {
    int statusCode = 200;
    //SOME CODE
    response.setStatus(statusCode);
}
```

Here is a nice answer listing a lot of possible solutions:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22869076/4823977

Comment: I think the OP is asking about WebSocket Close Status Codes, not HTTP Status Codes.

Comment: I updated the answer, I am curios if that is the case.