# JERSEY - returning javax.ws.rs.core.Response as a JSON object with either error:... or token:

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey

**EDIT**: Is there any way to return a simple object that has either:

- **token**
- **error**
- **error** *and* **details**

...without having to create new Objects.
**what's the most efficient and understandable way to do this?**

I am trying to make a login service that `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` (containing login credentials: username, password, consumer(boolean)).

If the credentials are valid I want to return a token, for future on the front end, and a *RESPONSE CODE* **OK**/**200**; something like this JSON object:

```
{"token":"aAKGKas211"}
```

Otherwise I have specific errors for every case and I want to return a different *RESPONSE CODE*, which would look something like this:

```
{"error":"Invalid username or password"}
```

I tried to add a String error (="Invalid username or password") to the Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity(error), but I'm getting the string as a string not as a JSON object..

this is how my code looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(@Context HttpServletRequest req, LoginInfo loginInfo) {
    CouponClientFacade facade = null;
    String token = null, error = null;

    // validate the REQUESTer's token, if he is already logged in return ERROR RESPONSE.
    System.out.println(loginInfo);
    System.out.println(req.getSession().getId());
    if (loginInfo == null)
        return Response.ok("Test").build();
    if (validateCredentials(loginInfo))
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity("Invalid username or password").build();


    try { // Try to login into administrator
        facade = ClientType.ADMIN.login(loginInfo.getUsername(), loginInfo.getPassword());
    } catch (Exception E) { // Couldn't login into administrator
        try {
            if (loginInfo.isCustomer()) // Try to login into CUSTOMER account
                facade = ClientType.CUSTOMER.login(loginInfo.getUsername(), loginInfo.getPassword());
            else // Try to login into COMPANY account
                facade = ClientType.COMPANY.login(loginInfo.getUsername(), loginInfo.getPassword());

        } catch (BadUsernamePassword e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(error=e.getMessage()).build();
        } catch (UnexpectedError e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(error=e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
    if (facade != null) {
        token = SessionManager.generateToken(req.getSession().getId(), facade);
        return Response.ok(token).build();
    } else return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(error="111").build();
}
```

edit:

Comment: Why do you need to re-invent the wheel? Why not use OAuth2 or JWT?

Comment: I am just trying to learn everything piece by piece. I don't want to copy and paste code, I want to understand the process and logic behind the scenes. This is my first API and I want to keep it basic and build it from the ground up for learning purposes... -The issue right now isn't the authentication, but returning a JSON object with `return Response.ok().entity(token).build()`
which comes out as:
`{'token':'aaAvbA21'}`
Instead of 
`aaAvbA21`

Comment: It's pretty basic I guess... but I couldn't find anything specific online, and some guy used: 
`public Response addUser(User user){

    User newUser = ...

    return Response.created(hateoas.buildLinkUri(newUser, "entity")).entity(restResponse).build();
}` which seems simple, but absolutely confused me when I tried to look into what hateoas is and how to implement something like that myself..

Comment: Try this `return new ResponseEntity<Type>(Body, HttpStatus.OK)`, instead of `return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(error=e.getMessage()).build();`

Answer (score 1):

**pass your token in "Authorization" header**

Basic Authentication provides a solution for this problem, although not very secure. With Basic Authentication, clients send it’s Base64 encoded credentials with each request, using HTTP [Authorization] header . That means each request is independent of other request and server may/does not maintain any state information for the client, which is good for scalability point of view.

A Word on HTTPS : For any sort of Security implementation, ranging from Basic authentication to a full fledged OAuth2 implementation, HTTPS is a must have. Without HTTPS, no matter what your implementation is, security is vulnerable to be compromised.

```
String plainClientCredentials="myusername:mypassword";
String base64ClientCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));

HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials);
```

which may in turn produce something like:

```
Authorization : Basic bXktdHJ1c3FOO1jbGllbnQ6c2VjcmV0...
```

Basic Authentication & Spring Security
With two steps, you can enable the Basic Authentication in Spring Security Configuration.
1. Configure httpBasic : Configures HTTP Basic authentication. [http-basic in XML]
2. Configure authentication entry point with BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint : In case the Authentication fails [invalid/missing credentials], this entry point will get triggered. It is very important, because we don’t want [Spring Security default behavior] of redirecting to a login page on authentication failure [ We don't have a login page].

Shown below is the complete Spring Security configuration with httpBasic and entry point setup.

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_TEST_REALM";

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("tom").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);//We don't need sessions to be created.
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint(){
        return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
}
```

And the actual Entry point, which will get triggerd if authentication failed. You can customize it to send custom content in response.

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;

public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, 
            final HttpServletResponse response, 
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Authentication failed, send error response.
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("MY_TEST_REALM");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

That’s all you need to configure basic security. Now let’s see everything in action, with our good old REST API

REST API
Simple Spring REST API, which serves user(s). A client can perform CRUD operations using Standard HTML verbs, compliant with REST style.

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.websystique.springmvc.model.User;
import com.websystique.springmvc.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work


    //-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    //-------------------Retrieve Single User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }



    //-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());

        if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
            System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    //------------------- Update a User --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

        if (currentUser==null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentUser.setName(user.getName());
        currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());

        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //------------------- Delete a User --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);

        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        userService.deleteUserById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


    //------------------- Delete All Users --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("Deleting All Users");

        userService.deleteAllUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand the token login and how to implement it.
A user logs in, I want to map his current session/id/device to a login token, this token links to facade which has DAO methods.
....I give him back the token so he has it and sends it in the header of each **auth required** request.

I know that I need to auth required services with @Secured, and I'll do that later.

I'm just confused as to how to send back a JSON object with the JAVAX Response builder, without having to create a special class for each case.

like in this case: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22869076/9382757)