# Getting HTTP response code 200 in API response even after returning ResponseEntity with HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse

I used the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250729/351903 -

```
@Path("api/path")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handshakeForTxn()
    {

       return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

I still get a 200 response status -

```
Server responded with a response on thread XNIO-3 task-2 2 < 200 2 < Content-Type: application/json
```

Although the response body contains a statusCodeValue which is set to 400 -

```
{ "headers": {}, "body": null, "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST", "statusCodeValue": 400 }
```

Comment: hi buddy you are using jersey right i dont think those annotations belong to spring check this link for returning a 400 response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together

Comment: This is working fine to return 400 response code. How to return an empty body?

Comment: just have to return null or empty in the entity please check i am not sure of this  Response.ok().entity("").build();

Comment: @ManojRamanan Add as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: i have added please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove

   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

RestController return JSON by default.

2. You controller should look like

   ```
   @RestController
   public class RegistrationController {

   @GetMapping("api/path")
   public ResponseEntity register() {
       return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
   }

   }
   ```
3. You could check code example here. https://github.com/alex-petrov81/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/bad-request-show-200

Comment: Ok, but my controller is not annotated with @RestController.

Comment: ok, it would be nice to see all of your controller code, and not only one method.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be

Response.noContent().status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build()

Response.ok().entity("").build();

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

For 200 -

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("").build();
```

For 400 -

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("").build();
```