# How to indicate the file name for saving to the browser from a REST service in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

i am trying to have a REST service return a zip file from the local harddrive .
Following is what i am doing ,

```
@Path("/interface3/{Ent_id}/{esf_app_id}/{esf_app_ver}")
public class Interface3Mock {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces("application/zip")
    public Response  callInterface3_text(
            @PathParam("Ent_id") Integer entitlement_id,
            @PathParam("eapp_id") String eapp_id,
            @PathParam("eapp_ver") String eapp_ver) {
        File f = new File("D:\\Documentation\\Documentation.zip");

        String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);

        return Response.ok(f, mt).build();

    }
}
```

Now when i use the browser ie. Internet Explorer and key in the url `http://localhost:9788/mockRESTServer/rest/interface3/123456/k123/l345`
i see a file download dialog that says "Do you want to save the file l345`.

i want it to ask me for the zip download ie. `D:\\Documentation\\Documentation.zip`.
But somehow it takes up the last parameter in the request URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return Response.ok(f, mt)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Documentation.zip")
        .build();
```

See [How to set response header in JAX-RS so that user sees download popup for Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621748/how-to-set-response-header-in-jax-rs-so-that-user-sees-download-popup-for-excel)

Comment: Can you please explain why this was going wrong ?  That will help me a lot in learning this stuff.   :)

Comment: IE uses the URL to determine the default filename to prompt the user to save the document as *if* this header is not present

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify what filename to use (which is always done via the standard **[`Content-Disposition` HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Responses)**) then it makes a guess. Clearly, it was guessing that the file name is whatever comes after the last `/` in the URL, which is pretty reasonable.