# What's the proper way to return a file as the response?

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-wink

Basically I need to provide REST service that would receive a String param, use that param to fetch a file from another system and then return the fetched file back as the response.

The effect should be the same as when a user clicks on a pdf or any other binary file link and the browser prompts him to save/download that file.

A couple of points:

- is it possible to stream the file (to send bytes as I receive them from source system). In other words, how to handle very large files?
- also related to streaming, when using regular HttpServletResponse, do I have to wait until a large file is completely read to `return response.build()`?

How do I go around doing this using Apache Wink?

PS Sorry, this may be trivial for Wink gurus, but I'm just starting to wrap my head around [developer guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/apache-wink-developer-guide.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return the `java.io.File` from your method. You can wrap it with `Response` if you like. Wink will handle the streaming. The streaming doesn't start when you call to `response.build()`, but rather when your method finishes.

If you want a correct download dialog, you should return the proper `Content-Disposition` header. See [How to set response header in JAX-RS so that user sees download popup for Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4621748/547779)