# JAX-RS (jersey) -> Angular.js via REST

Tags: java, rest, angularjs, jax-rs, cors

I have a jersey server up and running. When running from browser directly I get the correct response. However when I try to access the rest service from angular.js's $resource I get the following error in the console when trying to access to the correct url. I've tried to read all materials online, like http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-cross-domain-filter/ to setup a CORS filter, but the guide seems to be dated and cryptic. (im using the newest implementation of jersey).

> Failed to load resource: Origin localhost:63342 is not allowed
>   by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

method that makes the data I need available in jersey.

```
  @Path("/id/{id}")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public boolean validateSSN(@PathParam("id") String id) {
      IdValidator idv = new IdValidator(id);
      return idv.Validate();
  }
```

accessor method in angular.js:

```
services.factory('ReplyFactory', function ($resource) {
console.log("test");
return $resource(baseUrl + '/myproject/api/validate/id/:id', {id: '@id'},
    {'get': { method: 'GET' }});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Well what you need to do is to ensure that all responses from your resources have following http headers:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - specifies from which origins requests should be accepted (localhost:63342  in your case)
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` - specifies which headers are allowed to be used via CORS
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` - specifies which methods are allowed to be used via CORS

And there are other headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and etc.

So you just need to add at least `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your responses. How you can do it depends on your environment.

You can [manually define those headers on each resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621748/how-to-set-response-header-in-jax-rs-so-that-user-sees-download-popup-for-excel) .

You can [define Jersey filter](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html#JAX-RSFilters-Overridingresponsestatuscodeandheaders) to add CORS headers to all responses

You can [use servlet filter](https://bitbucket.org/thetransactioncompany/cors-filter) to add CORS headers to all responses

There are also specific solutions for [Tomcat](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Apache_Tomcat_.287.0.41_and_above.29) and [Jetty](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Jetty_.287_and_above.29)

There many ways how to do it but all of it is about the same thing - you just add an extra header to your server responses.