# Download CSV file via Rest

Tags: java, rest, csv, opencsv

Using OpenCSV,  I can successfully create a CSV file on disc, but what I really need is to allow users download the CSV with a download button, I don't need to save on disk, just download. Any ideas?

```
@GET
@Path("/downloadCsv")
public Object downloadCsv() {
        CSVWriter writer;
        FileWriter wr; 
      //Or should I use outputstream here?   
        wr= new FileWriter("MyFile.csv");
        writer = new CSVWriter(wr,',');
        for (Asset elem: assets) {
            writer.writeNext(elem.toStringArray());
        }
        writer.close();


}
```

EDIT: I do NOT want to save/read file on disc EVER

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To force "save as", you need to set the content disposition HTTP header in the response.  It should look like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.csv"
```

It looks like you're using JAX-RS.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621748/how-to-set-response-header-in-jax-rs-so-that-user-sees-download-popup-for-excel) shows how to set the header.  You can either write the CSV to the HTTP response stream and set the header there or return a `Response` object like so:

```
return Response.ok(myCsvText).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName).build();
```

You do not need to write to a `File` object in the middle of this process so can avoid writing to disk.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  One easy way is to get the string out of the CSVWriter.  I use JacksonCSV not OpenCSV, but I imagine it's fairly easy.  You could use a StringWriter instead of a FileWriter for example.

Comment: Yup.  Just write it to a string not the file.  Return a Response not an Object.  Try it out.

Answer (score 4):

First, you code cannot be compiled, right? Method `downloadCsv()` declares return type `Object` but does not return anything.

I'd change the declaration to `String downloadCsv()` and return the content of CSV as string. To do this use `StringWriter` instead of `FileWriter` and then say `return wr.toString()`.

The only thing that is missing here is content type. You annotate your method as `@Produces({"text/csv"})`.

I think, that's it.

Comment: if I return a string then will user get a browser save/open dialog box? thats what i need

Comment: It depends on configuration and type of user's browser. But the return type of method does not affect this process. The content type does.

Comment: As fare as I know default behavior of IE is to ask user where to store the file being downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

```
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".csv");
            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

            List<String[]> result = iSmsExportService.csvExport(columnNames);
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(osw, ';');
            csvWriter.writeAll(result);
            csvWriter.flush();
            csvWriter.close();
```

Downloading of CSV file has started after this.