# Java Resful Webserver. Send Excel sheet as response with 2 addtional variables

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Java Restful Webservices 
1.I need to send the Excel Sheet as Response. (I am able to Generate the Excel as response.)
2.I also need to send the 2 variables as response with Excel sheet how can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that'll probably work for most users would be to send the 2 variables as HTTP headers in the response (assuming the client knows to handle them) and to send the Excel document as an attachment. For the latter, just [set Content-disposition to attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621748/how-to-set-response-header-in-jax-rs-so-that-user-sees-download-popup-for-excel).

Comment: Using HTTP headers is probably the way to go. Their name should start with "X-", as they are nonstandard.