# Set JAX-RS response headers in implementation without exposing HttpServletResponse in interface

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, httpresponse

I have a RESTful server implementation as well as a library for clients to make the calls, all using JAX-RS. The server components are divided up into interface `FooResource` and implementation `FooResourceService`.

In order for the client and server libraries to share RESTful path and other definitions, I wanted to split out the `FooResource` interface into its own project:

```
@Path(value = "foo")
public interface FooResource {

  @GET
  public Bar getBar(@PathParam(value = "{id}") int id) {
```

I want to set some headers in the response. One easy way to do this is to use `@Context HttpServletResponse` in the method signature:

```
  public Bar getBar(@PathParam(value = "{id}") int id, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
```

But the problem is that this exposes implementation details in the interface. More specifically, it suddenly requires my REST definition project (which is shared between the client and server library) to pull in the `javax.servlet-api` dependency---something the client has no need up (or desire for).

**How can my RESTful resource service implementation set HTTP response headers without pulling in that dependency in the resource interface?**

I saw [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625289/421049) recommending I inject the HttpServletResponse as a class member. But how would this work if my resource service implementation is a singleton? Does it use some sort of proxy with thread locals or something that figures out the correct servlet response even though the singleton class is used simultaneously by multiple threads? Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer seems to be to inject an `HttpServletResponse` in the member variable of the implementation, as I noted that [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625289/421049) had indicated.

```
@Context  //injected response proxy supporting multiple threads
private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;
```

Even though peeskillet indicated that the semi-official list for Jersey doesn't list `HttpServletResponse` as one of the proxy-able types, when I traced through the code at least RESTEasy seems to be creating a proxy (`org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy@xxxxxxxx`). So as far as I can tell, thread-safe injection of a singleton member variable seems to be occurring.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076327/421049 .

Answer (score 2):

So injecting `HttpServletResponse` seems like a no go. Only certain proxy-able types are inject-able into singletons. I believe the complete list is as follows:

```
HttpHeaders, Request, UriInfo, SecurityContext
```

This is somewhat pointed out in the JAX-RS spec, but is explained more clearly in the Jersey reference guide

> The exception exists for specific request objects which can injected even into constructor or class fields. For these objects the runtime will inject proxies which are able to simultaneously server more request. These request objects are `HttpHeaders`, `Request`, `UriInfo`, `SecurityContext`. These proxies can be injected using the `@Context` annotation.

`SecurityContext` may be Jersey specific, as it's not stated in the spec, but I'm not sure.

Now those types mentioned above don't really do much for you because they are all request contexts and nothing to set the response.

One Idea though is to use a [`javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html), along with the `HttpHeaders` to set a temporary request header. You can access that header through the `ContainerRequestContext` passed to the `filter` method.  Then just set the response header through the `ContainerResponseContext`, also passed to the `filter` method. If the the header is not specific to the context of that resource method, then it's even easier. Just set the header in the filter.

But let's say the header is dependent on the execution of the resource method. Then you could do something like

```
@Singleton
@Path("/singleton")
public class SingletonResource {

    @Context
    javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders headers;

    @GET
    public String getHello() {

        String result = resultFromSomeCondition(new Object());
        headers.getRequestHeaders().putSingle("X-HELLO", result);
        return "Hello World";
    }

    private String resultFromSomeCondition(Object condition) {
        return "World";
    }
}
```

Then the `ContainerResponseFilter` might look something like this

```
@Provider
public class SingletonContainerResponseFilter 
                            implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc, 
            ContainerResponseContext crc1) throws IOException {
        String header = crc.getHeaderString("X-HELLO");
        crc1.getHeaders().putSingle("X-HELLO", "World");
    } 
}
```

And just so only the singleton classes run through this filter, we can simply use a [`@NameBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SingletonHeader {}

...

@SingletonHeader
public class SingletonResource {

...

@SingletonHeader
public class SingletonContainerResponseFilter 
                        implements ContainerResponseFilter {
```

This is the only way I can think to handle this situation.

---

**Resources:**

- [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)
- [Name Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e8530)

Comment: See my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27648777/421049) here. I tried it and it seems to work with RESTEasy.

Comment: So it works when you do package scanning with `@Singleton` annotation, but when you register with `getSingletons()` in the `Application` class, that's when it fails (the NPE I was getting). In the latter case, with Jersey, I would just get an exception saying something like "Not within a Request scope". `@Singleton` still fails with Jersey also. Just some more FYIs for any others who come across this.

Comment: Makes sense though, if the container is to handle the injection, why instantiating it in `getSingletons()` doesn't work.

Comment: Strange... I'm using it in `getSingletons()` with no problem. In fact I'm even delegating to a `PicoContainer` to do the actual instantiation, so whatever wrapping must be happening after the instances are returned.

Comment: Yes, in RESTEasy at least what gets installed in the container is an actual `FooResourceService`, but its private member has been injected with a proxy.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface FooResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response getBar(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        //Do some logic on bar
        return Response.ok().entity(bar).header("header-name", "header-value").build()
    }
}
```

Returns a JSON representation of the instance of `bar` with a status code 200 and header `header-name` with value `header-value`. It should look something along the lines of:

```
{
    "bar-field": "bar-field-value",
    "bar-field-2": "bar-field-2"
}
```

Comment: I don't want a `Response` return in the signature. I want a `Bar` return in the signature.

Comment: My browser is not doing software development. My developers are. I want to create a clean API that indicates semantically what is being returned. I want to relegate JAX-RS specific items to annotations and implementation code.